# Update SQL Server database via a datagridview in C# on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-update, datagridviewrow

When the user double click on a row on the datagridview, the relevant details appear in the textboxes.

User can edit the details and click on Update button to save the updates on the SQL database.

Note : CustomerID is an identity column in the customer table on the database

Please help with the C# code.

[Capture of Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDO7T.jpg)

Comment: Also, what is your question? There is no code, you don't show any details, just a linked screen shot of the UI. I vote to close this as it is too vague and broad of a question.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you've just started to learn WinForms & C#. Firstly, I would recommend that at this stage, you should keep the datagrid view as just a view.

Second, it would be better if you start off by making a simple search button to query your SQL database and populate the textboxes accordingly. Then you can keep on building up your application as you get more sophisticated with how everything works.

Step-by-step dude, nobody is just going to paste an entire code here specifically for you, and even if somebody does, you'll learn nothing.